# how to make button disabled with true and false methods in angular 17

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my first time using Angular 17. I found a problem when I clicked the register button. I wanted to make the button disabled. After the process, the button was not disabled again.

// /src/app/component/regsiter/regsiter.component.ts

```
// /src/app/component/regsiter/regsiter.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrl: './register.component.css'
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  loadingScreen: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void{
  }

  register(){
    this.loadingScreen = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.email == '') {
        alert('Please enter Email');
        return;
      }
      if (this.password == '') {
        alert('Please enter Password');
        return;
      }
  
      this.auth.register(this.email, this.password);
  
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
    }, 5000)

    this.loadingScreen = true;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card shadow">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <h4 class="text-dark text-muted">Regsite</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" class="form-control" name="password">
              </div>
              <button type="button" [disabled]="loadingScreen" class="btn btn-info" (click)="register()">Regsiter</button>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <a href="/login" style="text-decoration: none;">Login Now</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how to make a button

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="loadingScreen" class="btn btn-info" (click)="register()">Register</button>
```

when clicked it becomes disabled and after 5 seconds of processing the button is no longer disabled

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your variable to **false** after 5 seconds in setTimeout block.

```
  register(){
    this.loadingScreen = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.email == '') {
        alert('Please enter Email');
        return;
      }
      if (this.password == '') {
        alert('Please enter Password');
        return;
      }
  
      this.auth.register(this.email, this.password);
  
      this.email = '';
      this.password = '';
      this.loadingScreen = false;

    }, 5000)

  }
```